# HoloLens can't pair with my PC in developer mode

Tags: uwp, hololens

I try to create a shared experience with two HoloLens 2.

I have finished creating my app so I have tried it on my first HoloLens 2. I succeeded in deploying and running my app on it.
So I take the HoloLens of another department of my company. They told me to reinitialize this one. So I do it and then, I follow the tutorial to deploy an app on HoloLens :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/using-visual-studio

And I had this error while deploying it through a USB cable :

> DEP6957 : Échec de la connexion à l'appareil '127.0.0.1' à l'aide de
> l'authentification universelle. Vérifiez que le mode
> d'authentification distant approprié est spécifié dans les paramètres
> de débogage du projet. COMException - Aucune connexion n’a pu être
> établie car l’ordinateur cible l’a expressément refusée. (Exception de
> HRESULT : 0x8007274D) [0x8007274D]

This error is printed before asking to pair my PC and HoloLens 2.

So I tried to update The Hololens to Windows 10 version 2004 there is a problem during the deploiement with the code :

> 0x80073afc

Does anyone have an idea to solve my problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to error code DEP6957, most of the solution is restarting headset or unpairing and then pairing it again. You can try following to fix it:

First, please make sure developer mode turned on **both** the Visual Studio computer and the HoloLens. It is a prerequisite for deploying an app. And then, make sure the USB Device connectivity component has been installed in Visual Studio, if not, you can install it with Visual Studio Installer.

After this, unpair all devices in Setting from your HoloLens and restart your device. After the device restarts, deploy your project to your device, the first time Visual Studio deploys it, you will be prompted for a PIN to pair your device again.

Answer (score 0):

I have solve my problem :

It was in Device Manager : the microsoft HoloLens was disabled in the Univers Serial Bus Device. So I make it enabled and then I deploy my project using Visual Studio and I could pair my device.

Answer (score 0):

While I am glad that people are helping unblock this solution. I think it would be best if you looked into alternative methods of app install. Such as using Device Portal, or Provisioning Packages. This way the linked computer does not need to be configured with visual studio, source code, ect. If you start to scale distributing your app you'll find it more manageable.